# What does "What Larks, Pip" mean in The Best Exotic Marigold Hotel?

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, dialogue, the-best-exotic-marigold-hotel

In The Best Exotic Marigold Hotel, Bill Nighy's character, Douglas, says to Judi Dench's character Evelyn:

> "What Larks, Pip"

To which she replies (getting on the coach):

> "Well, let's hope so"

The googles give me an out of context answer, which (for me at least) doesn't make sense (at least in their situation).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What larks Pip is a phrase from the Charles Dickens book Great Expectations, used in the book to mean have fun, or to reminisce of fun/good times in the past.

> verb (used without object)
>   to have fun; frolic; romp. [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/lark)

In this context of the movie it most likely means "have fun" or "have a good time".

Comment: @cmp had to read Great Expectations twice in highschool haha.

Comment: Oh I see; perfect question for you then :-)

Answer (score 2):

A "Lark" is an informal English (UK) idiom for a fun adventure

[**Oxford Dictionary**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/lark)

> Something done for fun, especially something mischievous or daring; an amusing adventure or escapade: